# Install hadoop plugin for eclipse oxygen

Tags: eclipse, hadoop

I am trying to install hadoop plugin for eclipse oxygen ... but am not able to make it work properly.. i am not getting any option to create a map reduce project .. can some one please let me know how to go abt installing the hadoop eclipse plugin ? I am unable to use the install new software feature - I have downloaded the hadoop-eclipse-plugin-2.6.0.jar but am not able to install the same as that is giving me an error sayin no site exists that this location. Also, copying the plugin at the eclipse/plugin folder doesn't work either  ?

Please help!

Comment: Copy it to the `dropins` folder.

Comment: thanks a ton ...it worked

Answer (score 0):

Copy it to the `dropins` folder of your Eclipse installation directory.

See also: [Eclipse help - The dropins folder and supported file layouts](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html)